# Cleaning beetle tracks in wooden floor during sanding

Tags: flooring, hardwood-floor, sanding

I'm renovating / rehabilitating a wooden floor, which is probably about 60 to 100 years old. I used a random orbital sander to clear a small section as a test, with this result:

[image: Section of floor sanded]

The problem is that some of the boards are in very poor condition, eaten by beetle over the years:

[image: Beetle tracks in the boards]

I'm concerned that if I sand further, especially with a drum sander, by the time I've sanded out those tracks, I won't have much floor left. Alternatively, is there a way to clean those tracks, so that when I varnish or oil the floor, they will be wood coloured, not 100-year-old-dirt coloured?

Comment: those tracks were probably there before the log was cut into boards

Comment: Lol, I should clarify - I'm not talking about the diagonal lines between the boards! I'm asking about the pockmarks and the little dots and squiggles where the beetles have bored ;)

Comment: Frankly I consider them attractive. Shows the character and age of the wood. Your choice of course in what appearance you want, but showing the history might not be a bad thing.

Comment: I'm with jsotoloa on this - imo it's much more likely that the beetles did that before of very shortly after the logs were cut into boards, and almost certainly long before the boards were laid down as flooring.

Comment: Also check if the polish will leave a stain around each hole - ask around.

Comment: I mean modern polish is applied, and then blue/green stain diffuses though the polish to leave it quite ugly. Sand and test on part of the underside of the floor?